# Error on clicked functions javascript and zindex

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering on why my code for this website inst working. I defined all the neccessarys (funtions and css) however I am still getting errors such as "clicked is not defined" however in the script it is. It is supposed to bring the clicked image to the front using javascript. The code just changes the zindex, bringing it to the front.

Why isn't this working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body
{
 background-image: url("http://logar.gitastudent.online/images/background.png");
}

#img1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#img2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img5 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img6 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img7 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img8 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 70px;
    top: 70px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img9 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#img10 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
    top: 90px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#img11 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#img12 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 110px;
    top: 110px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#img13 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    top: 120px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#img14 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 130px;
    top: 130px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#img15 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
    top: 140px;
    z-index: 1;
}

<script>

var clicked = function(id) {
 
 document.getElementById("img1").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img2").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img3").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img4").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img5").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img6").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img7").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img8").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img9").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img10").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img11").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img12").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img13").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img14").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img15").style.zIndex = "1";
 
 document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex = "2";
 
}

</script>

</style>
</head>
<body>

 <img id="img1" src="https://i0.wp.com/www.commodore.ca/gallery/hardware/Commodore%20Educator.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Dysan_floppy_disk_01.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img3" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/children-playing-on-grass_1098-504.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img4" src="https://afv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/iccbaby_09.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                            onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img5" src="https://qzprod.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/rtx2fw23.jpg?quality=80&strip=all" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img6" src="https://img.wonderhowto.com/img/53/47/63580328862338/0/study-for-white-hat-hacker-associate-certification-cwa.1280x600.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"            onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img7" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BEDVjg5y0Hg/maxresdefault.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                              onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img8" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Dysan_floppy_disk_01.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img9" src="http://www.vintageisthenewold.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/PrintPreview-520x245.png" width="50%" height="80%"                     onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img10" src="http://www.guidebookgallery.org/pics/gui/startupshutdown/splash/win95-1-1.png" width="50%" height="80%"                       onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img11" src="http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/075/880/bb9.png" width="50%" height="80%"                          onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img12" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/roblox-apocalypse-rising/images/5/59/Doge-meme-Text-Art.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20131125030607" width="50%" height="80%"          onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img13" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52e15a97e4b012e6d957fc62/5578e529e4b0204b4bc0d3c5/5907cce69de4bbccbb450a8f/1493683468194/Family-Silhouette-3.jpg?format=1000w" width="50%" height="80%"  onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img14" src="https://mrayton.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/thecross.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                            onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img15" src="http://www.ecnmag.com/sites/ecnmag.com/files/3%2C5_DD_floppy_%28720_KB%29_back.jpeg" width="50%" height="80%"                      onclick="clicked(this)">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have script tag inside style tag, change it and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems, one, `script` is not recognized inside `style`, and so the `clicked` function was undefined. And you pass `this` to `clicked`, which passes an image object. You can read the `id` attribute by using `id.id`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body
{
 background-image: url("http://logar.gitastudent.online/images/background.png");
}

#img1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#img2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img5 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img6 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img7 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img8 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 70px;
    top: 70px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img9 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#img10 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
    top: 90px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#img11 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#img12 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 110px;
    top: 110px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#img13 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    top: 120px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#img14 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 130px;
    top: 130px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#img15 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
    top: 140px;
    z-index: 1;
}
</style>
<script>

var clicked = function(id) {
 
 document.getElementById("img1").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img2").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img3").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img4").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img5").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img6").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img7").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img8").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img9").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img10").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img11").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img12").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img13").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img14").style.zIndex = "1";
 document.getElementById("img15").style.zIndex = "1";
 
 document.getElementById(id.id).style.zIndex = "2";
 
}

</script>

  
</head>
<body>

 <img id="img1" src="https://i0.wp.com/www.commodore.ca/gallery/hardware/Commodore%20Educator.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Dysan_floppy_disk_01.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img3" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/children-playing-on-grass_1098-504.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img4" src="https://afv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/iccbaby_09.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                            onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img5" src="https://qzprod.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/rtx2fw23.jpg?quality=80&strip=all" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img6" src="https://img.wonderhowto.com/img/53/47/63580328862338/0/study-for-white-hat-hacker-associate-certification-cwa.1280x600.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"            onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img7" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BEDVjg5y0Hg/maxresdefault.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                              onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img8" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Dysan_floppy_disk_01.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img9" src="http://www.vintageisthenewold.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/PrintPreview-520x245.png" width="50%" height="80%"                     onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img10" src="http://www.guidebookgallery.org/pics/gui/startupshutdown/splash/win95-1-1.png" width="50%" height="80%"                       onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img11" src="http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/075/880/bb9.png" width="50%" height="80%"                          onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img12" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/roblox-apocalypse-rising/images/5/59/Doge-meme-Text-Art.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20131125030607" width="50%" height="80%"          onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img13" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52e15a97e4b012e6d957fc62/5578e529e4b0204b4bc0d3c5/5907cce69de4bbccbb450a8f/1493683468194/Family-Silhouette-3.jpg?format=1000w" width="50%" height="80%"  onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img14" src="https://mrayton.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/thecross.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                            onclick="clicked(this)">
 <img id="img15" src="http://www.ecnmag.com/sites/ecnmag.com/files/3%2C5_DD_floppy_%28720_KB%29_back.jpeg" width="50%" height="80%"                      onclick="clicked(this)">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced the script. And change the `document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex = "2";` to `id.style.zIndex = "2";`

```js
     function clicked(id) {
    
     document.getElementById("img1").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img2").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img3").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img4").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img5").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img6").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img7").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img8").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img9").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img10").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img11").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img12").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img13").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img14").style.zIndex = "1";
     document.getElementById("img15").style.zIndex = "1";
     
     id.style.zIndex = "2";
     
    }
```

```css
    body
    {
     background-image: url("http://logar.gitastudent.online/images/background.png");
    }

    #img1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #img2 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 10px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #img3 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top: 20px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #img4 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        top: 30px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #img5 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 40px;
        top: 40px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #img6 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #img7 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 60px;
        top: 60px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #img8 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 70px;
        top: 70px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #img9 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 80px;
        top: 80px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #img10 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 90px;
        top: 90px;
        z-index: 1;
    }


    #img11 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px;
        z-index: 1;
    }


    #img12 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 110px;
        top: 110px;
        z-index: 1;
    }


    #img13 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 120px;
        top: 120px;
        z-index: 1;
    }


    #img14 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 130px;
        top: 130px;
        z-index: 1;
    }


    #img15 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 140px;
        top: 140px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="https://i0.wp.com/www.commodore.ca/gallery/hardware/Commodore%20Educator.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Dysan_floppy_disk_01.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img3" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/children-playing-on-grass_1098-504.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img4" src="https://afv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/iccbaby_09.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                            onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img5" src="https://qzprod.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/rtx2fw23.jpg?quality=80&strip=all" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img6" src="https://img.wonderhowto.com/img/53/47/63580328862338/0/study-for-white-hat-hacker-associate-certification-cwa.1280x600.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"            onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img7" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BEDVjg5y0Hg/maxresdefault.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                              onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img8" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Dysan_floppy_disk_01.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                        onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img9" src="http://www.vintageisthenewold.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/PrintPreview-520x245.png" width="50%" height="80%"                     onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img10" src="http://www.guidebookgallery.org/pics/gui/startupshutdown/splash/win95-1-1.png" width="50%" height="80%"                       onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img11" src="http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/075/880/bb9.png" width="50%" height="80%"                          onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img12" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/roblox-apocalypse-rising/images/5/59/Doge-meme-Text-Art.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20131125030607" width="50%" height="80%"          onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img13" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52e15a97e4b012e6d957fc62/5578e529e4b0204b4bc0d3c5/5907cce69de4bbccbb450a8f/1493683468194/Family-Silhouette-3.jpg?format=1000w" width="50%" height="80%"  onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img14" src="https://mrayton.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/thecross.jpg" width="50%" height="80%"                            onclick="clicked(this)">
     <img id="img15" src="http://www.ecnmag.com/sites/ecnmag.com/files/3%2C5_DD_floppy_%28720_KB%29_back.jpeg" width="50%" height="80%"                      onclick="clicked(this)">
```